# How to get CA2100 SQL injection warning in calling methods

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection, fxcop

I have a helper method to prevent a lot of copy and paste. I want to make sure calling methods of my helper method "MyExecuteSQLQuery" will be checked against rule "CA2100: Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities". How can I achieve that?

So in other words, i want to get a CA2100 warning for something like that:

```
MyExecuteSQLQuery("update credentials set password = '" + password +"' where id = " + id);
```

Helper method:

```
public static int MyExecuteSQLQuery(string sql, int timeout = 30)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionstring))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            if (timeout != 30)
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;
            }

            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're fundamentally breaking people's best ability to avoid SQL injection by insisting that the entire query be submitted as a single string. The single strongest way to avoid injection is to use parameters.

Comment: Have you considered using something like Dapper rather than adding methods like this?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have also a helper method with parameters, but I want to make sure nobody will use this helper method with a risk of SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a very good idea. I imagine that it's possible to add your method to an analyser, but it is probably easier to refactor your method to take a `MySqlCommand` instead, maybe something like this:

```
public static int MyExecuteSQLQuery(MySqlCommand cmd, int timeout = 30)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(DBConnectionstring))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;
        
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

}

And then you would get your error/warning when you construct your `MySqlCommand`

Comment: Well, but it's nicer to call it like that:

`MyExecuteSQLQuery("update x set a=1 where b=2");



instead of:


`using (var sql = new MySqlCommand("update x set a=1 where b=2"))
`{
`MyExecuteSQLQuery(sql);
`}